# The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. For Loop and Button

Tags: flutter, button

I am trying to create a button within a for loop as the loop is connected to the main dart. Everything else is running fine but then I try to put in the raisebutton I seem to get these errors depending on the dart package I am using stating:
package:path/path.dart Context context  Type: Context
The system path context.
This differs from a context created with new Context in that its Context.current is always the current working directory, rather than being set once when the context is created.

or

dart:js JsObject get context
The JavaScript global object, usually window.

I don't know if what I am doing is right or not, please help.

[image]

Here is part of my main dart where the for loop is suppose to go inside as the for loop is within a different dart file

[image]

Comment: Please read up on the proper way to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Do not share screenshots of code. Copy/paste or type the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are instantiating `MyMenu` so often or why you are passing `MyMenu` instance variables into a `MyMenu` instance method. You may want to look at a better way to structure your code.

But to answer your question, you have no access to the current `BuildContext` within your `MyMenu` class. Quickest remedy: pass the `BuildContext` as a parameter to `buildMenuItemsList`.

```
buildMenuItemsList(Section section, BuildContext context) { ... }

MyMenu().buildMenuItemsList(MyMenu().getSections()[index], context),
```